# Where are the sample books stored in the iBooks for Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, macos, books

I'm doing an accessibility stuff and I need to access the source file (.epub file) of the sample books in iBooks for Mac OS X. I did look for one at `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks` but that only stored *bought* books. Does anyone know?

(My OS is the newest version of Yosemite.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you can find the iBooks source files:

Go to Library > Containers > com.apple.BKAgentService > Data > Documents > iBooks

Or simply type 'iBooks' in the searcher of Finder and click on the folder named iBooks.

Comment: Hold on `Option` key when you click `Go` menu to reveal `Library`.

Answer (score 1):

**Just to complete the answers, many other files actually sit in the icloud drive but hidden.  That is on top of the directory mention mentioned for some files as stated above.  In particular, all PDFs are stored hiddend.**

These days you can send things to icloud drive under different apps but Apple not telling you where it is.

If you do not want to go through terminal (and use ls -al etc.) try this:

- copy a named pdf say "a=pdf.pdf" to ibook
- search for a=pdf.pdf
- if there is no such second copy, 
  try this further

  add pdf as a kind into the search field (whatever the search is)
  search for "a"  instead of "a=pdf.pdf" (or any other possible filename)
  just a
  your file would appear (as the original copy)
  click the open the enclosing folder

It works in El Captain just a moment ago.